# Add extra text to cell of has text otherwise leave blank

Tags: excel

I want to be able to add a specific word(s) to the start of another excel cells text if text is in that cell otherwise show nothing.
Example: cell A1 says - name is John Doe.
What we really want that to say if text has been entered is to add "My" name is John Doe.
But if cell is empty don't display the word "My"

I plan to CONCATENATE several cells to form a string sentence but struggling with this one part of the puzzle.

Summary, if cell has text display extra text as start otherwise don't display.
Thanks

Comment: CAn you show us an example of your data and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Please try `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","My "&A1)`

[image: SO18263709 example]

See [=IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your help, it has worked as required, much appreciated